# Is there a way to prevent padding of a composed class

Tags: c++, padding

Assuming a 64 bit machine:

If I start with a class A:

```
struct A
{
    int* a1; //8
    int* a2; //8 
    uint16_t a3; //2
    uint16_t a4; //2

    uint32_t a5; //4
    uint32_t a6; //4
    uint32_t a7; //4
};
```

Now all the individual members have correct alignment, the size of `A` is 32 bytes, and the offset from `a5` to `a1` is 20 bytes

Now, if I try to refactor this as follows:

```
struct A_part1
{
    int* a1; //8
    int* a2; //8 
    uint16_t a3; //2
    uint16_t a4; //2
};

struct A_new
{
    A_part1 a1; 
    uint32_t a5; //4
    uint32_t a6; //4
    uint32_t a7; //4
};
```

Now the size of `A_new` is 40 bytes, because `A_part1` is padded up to 24 bytes and `A_new` is subsequently padded from 36 up to 40 bytes.

Presumably the compiler is trying to ensure that contiguous `A_part1`'s will be aligned.

If I know that I will only ever use `A_part1` in `A`,  is the only option I have to use a `pragma` pack on `a_part`1 here to ensure that `A_new` will have the same characteristics as the original `A`?

Comment: Note that a) pragma's are generally not considered portable. 2) Different compilers might have similar pragma's, but they are not necessarily named the same.  3) Compiler options (i.e. optimization levels) might change the layout compared to previous settings, and you probably need to test that the pragma's still do what you want.  On the other hand, my experience with pragma's in C++ is generally that they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: There is no way in standard C++ to specify the layout of padding of your `struct`s so you are stuck with compiler-specific control mechanisms like `#pragma pack`.

Comment: @skimon  There are several ways to specify the layout and padding of a memory structure / class.  Pragma might be easy, but is generally not portable, and I have not evaluated pragma's behaviour in the face of compiler option changes.  My answer below is one of 3 "standard C++" techniques (i.e. portable and without pragmas) that I have used on production code.

Answer (score 1):

> If I know that I will only ever use A_part1 in A, is the only option I
>   have to use a pragma pack on a_part1 here to ensure that A_new will
>   have the same characteristics as the original A?

No.  pragma is not the only way to specify the layout and padding.

In an embedded software I once worked on, we found several ways around the pragma issue.

---

Neither C nor C++ provide memory layout semantics.

But one technique that is easy to understand, at least on a field by field basis, is to explicitly code where the bytes reside in a class or struct.  With refactoring and the addition of small byte movement methods, the effort reduces substantially.

Note: Seven fields is small and thus 'easy'. Fifty fields is tiresome. Hundred's of fields is "lets write some code to write some code."  Your tolerance will vary.

This  technique moves bytes explicitly where desired, byte-by-byte, into the class data.  Advantages: 1) no padding (unless you want it).  2) Insensitive to compiler options changes.  3) Portable.

Small example (compiles, but not tested) (note: Arbitrary endian choice, we used the conventional endian-transformation)

```
class A
{
   //   int* a1;     //8  0..7
   //   int* a2;     //8  8..15
   //   uint16_t a3; //2  16..17
   //   uint16_t a4; //2  18..19
   //
   //   uint32_t a5; //4  etc
   //   uint32_t a6; //4
   //   uint32_t a7; //4
   // ...

   // modify field a3
   void a3(uint16_t val) {
      // if needed, correct val for destination endianess ------vvv
      data[Oa3+0] = static_cast<uint8_t>((val >> 0) & 0xff); // LSB
      data[Oa3+1] = static_cast<uint8_t>((val >> 8) & 0xff); // MSB
   }

   // access field a3
   uint16_t  a3() {
      // if needed, correct val for endianess ---------------------vvv
      uint16_t val = static_cast<uint16_t>((data[Oa3+0] << 0) + // LSB
                                           (data[Oa3+8] << 8)); // MSB
      return (val);
   }

   // continue for each field

private:
   enum {
      Oa1 = 0, // Offset a1
      Oa2 = 8,
      Oa3 = 16
      //... etc
   };

   uint8_t data[(8+8+2+2+(3*4))]; 
};
```